# Is this str_replace the same as this preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Just a short question, will these two lines **always** give the same result, considering, that an XML request or response is given?

```
str_replace( array( "\n", "\t", "\r", "\r\n" ), '', trim( $xml ) );

preg_replace( '#>\s+<#', '><', $xml );
```

If no, how can I make a `preg_replace` like that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to replace a str_replace with a preg_replace? Never use preg_replace if str_replace can do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `preg_replace` is more constrained than the `str_replace` (it only matches whitespace outside angle brackets) and `\s` includes the space character. Additionally, a string like `<blah> \r \n \t TEXT \t\t</blah>` would not be replaced, instead the whitespace would be kept.

In fact, the two are nothing alike asides from both affecting whitespace in some way.

The equivalent `preg_replace` to your `str_replace` would just be `('/[\r\n\t]/','',$xml)`

Comment: Thanx a lot. I guess I should stick to the old `str_replace` then ;)

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, if you have something like:

```
<tag att="1"
att="2"
att="3">text</tag>
```

They will give a different result. However, if I can give an advice, don't use regex for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

They are not similar because:

1. the regex only handles whitespaces between brackets (I guess this is wanted because you don't want to destroy the xml?!)
2. \s also will also remove "normal" whitespace characters and other [non-printable characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#nonprint) (I think that's OK?)
3. preg_replace normally works on single lines, so it might be that you still have linebreaks afterwards
   => to avoid that, use the ["m" modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

If the first variant works fine for you, then in my opinion it is better then the regex. Otherwise this might be the searched one:

```
preg_replace( '#>\s+<#m', '><', $xml );
```